# Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable' in swift5

Tags: swift, codable

I have one payload format as following that I need to pass as argument into request to get response. How can I structure the payload? I try to set one `struct Person` as `Codable` but I have the error like:

```
Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable'
Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable'
```

Code:

```
/// let payload = {"name:": "john", "age": 12, "birthplace": {"latitude": 123.45, "longitude": 11.123}, workHistory: [{"google": "1 year"}, {"amazon": 1}]}

struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var birthplace: Birthplace,
    var workHistory: [String: Any]

    struct Birthplace: Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
}

func request<T: Codable>(url: URL, method: String, body: Encodable? = nil) -> T? {
    let headers: [String: String] = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
    ...
    return response
}

request(url: URL, method: String, body: payload)
```

Comment: `Any` is not `Codable`.  I would recommend changing the backend to return a consistent structure (i.e. the work history to be an array of `[String: String]`) and then define types accordingly.

Comment: the problem for me is I have multiple layer json object under workHistory like `{workHistory: {a: {aaaa: aaaa: {}}}}` it is pretty hard for me to build the structure for it

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/ will build it for you. If you have a specific issue (like dynamic keys), then show the JSON you're having trouble with. Your data is absolutely not `Any`. (Would it be legal to have a UIViewController or CBPeripheral as a value? If not, it's not Any.) What output do you want from the `"1 year"` and `1` conflict, or does that really exist in your data?

Comment: jacobcan118, I understand that it might have a rich structure, but you're almost always better having a type that captures this complexity in all its richness. That having been said, you can use `JSONSerialization` instead of `JSONDecoder` if you really must, and manually build your objects, but it generally leads to even more complicated and brittle code, IMHO. Personally, I'd suggest editing your question with more representative payload snippet with representative examples of the actual structures, and we can better advise you.

Comment: So basically my payload is generated from another requwst's response. I do not even know how many layers/ structure I may have. At this moment I can just use Any to present all

Comment: You can have `Codable` that captures arbitrary depth (e.g., you can have a `Codable` structure that represents a family tree of arbitrary depth, for example). And, I confess that I have a hard time imagining an employment structure that couldn't be represented in a `Codable` structure. But, if you're saying that you must (or simply want to) stick with `Any`, then, fine, do not use `Codable`/`JSONDecoder`, and use `JSONSerialization` and manually build your objects yourself. You might consider [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), too, a `JSONSerialization`-based solution.

Comment: Can you provide the example for `e.g., you can have a Codable structure that represents a family tree of arbitrary depth, for example). And, I confess that I have a hard time` ? Let's say I have at least 5 depths object?

Comment: I will close this one and provide more detail for following question

Comment: you will need to pass the type to the generic function like this T.type. and the consumer will pas it like this Person.self